# How much battery does an ODB Bluetooth reader suck?

Tags: electrical, obd-ii

I'm planning on using an ODB Bluetooth reader on my car and leaving it plugged in to use apps like Dash and Torque. 
It's a daily driver so I'm not that worried about depleting the car's battery, but I was curious how much amperage that port would suck.

Comment: For those interested, the obdii scanner I bought (a cheap 20€ one) didn't discharge my car in two days of inaction (I wouldn't risk further though).

Comment: The answer below is only about the bluetooth network card's consumption, but on that adapter there is way more than that (there's a microcontroller and adapters that convert the K-line's and CAN voltage levels to the ones accepted by the microcontroller), so I would say it always uses about 100 mA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure of your exact solution, but Brian Blum of [Texas Instruments](http://web.archive.org/web/20140801032026/http:/www.iar.com/Global/Resources/Viewpoints/Bluetooth%C2%AE%20low%20energy,%20A%20Very%20Low%20Power%20Solution.pdf) says the amperage draw depends on what state the device is in, of which there are seven states. According to the document in the link, it draws as follows:

- State 1 (wake-up) - 6.1mA
- State 2 (pre-processing) - 8.1 mA
- State 3 (pre-RX) - 12.3 mA
- State 4 (RX) - 22.3 mA
- State 5 (Rx-to-Tx) - 11.1 mA
- State 6 (Tx) - 29.3 mA
- State 7 (Post processing) - 8.1 mA

These are for the device listed in the document, but should be about the same. As you can see, these are very small amounts of draw. I would also bet, if you look at your device specs, when the vehicle is off, your device is off: no power consumption during this time. For your edification, it takes 1000 mA to make one (1) Amp.